# APK file is zipalign verified but still will not upload to Google Play

Tags: android

I am uploading my first APK file to google play but I am getting following error.  **You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.**

I have verified that the apk is zipaligned but I continue to get this error. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How have you verified? Did you export as release, sign, then manually run zipalign?

Comment: Yes Sir. When I ran the Zip Align I was given a verification successful message so I am assuming that means my apk is aligned. But you know what they say about "assume" ;)

Comment: LOL, indeed! I've only ever seen this when zipalign wasn't run, or was run before the APK was signed. It sounds odd, but you align after you sign it. Beyond that, I can't think of why this would happen.

Comment: Well thank you very much anyway :)

Comment: Another q: when you ran zipalign, did you give it an alignment of "4"?  That's the only valid value at this time.

Comment: Any luck i face this too..

Comment: Well, I face this too. Don't getting what's wrong!!